# Convert a node.js buffer to string and then to JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, buffer

I have a node.js readstream which emits a buffer and using toString() function i convert the buffer to string and after that when i try to convert the string to JSON via JSON.parse() function it throws parse error.

Is there a best way to convert buffer to string and then that string to JSON?

JSON String looks like below,

[{"data1": 1487328824948, "encrypt": false, "version": "1.0.0", "data2": "value2", "data3": "value3", "data4": "value4", "data5": "value5"},{"data1": 148732882448, "encrypt": false, "version": "1.0.0", "data2": "value2", "data3": "value3", "data4": "value4", "data5": "value5"}.........]

Comment: can you please post string , converted by toString()

Comment: @shivshankar i added the string

Answer (score 3):

```
var buf = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(obj));
var temp = JSON.parse(buf.toString());
```

Comment: What is `obj`. It doesn't seem to be a stream. And I don't see the point of converting `obj` to JSON string, then to buffer, back to JSON string again and then parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the right way, but it seems likely that your readstream isn't finishing reading the input before you call JSON.parse(). Therefore the JSON.parse() call only parses part of your JSON string and then you get the error.

Try making sure the read() finishes - use [readSync()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)?

Comment: the readstream that i'm dealing here comes out of a tar.gz file and it continuously streams the JSON like string, as the data comes, in the .on('data') listener i do the buffer to string conversion and then via JSON.parse convert it to object so i can start parsing it. Not sure if readSync to help here and also might slow down the process since the tar.gz size is pretty large.

Comment: i added the JSON string that i'm dealing with, similar to the one that i posted it keeps coming out of tar.gz